# Excel Comparing Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a spread sheet that has computers in the furthest left column with their specs in columns B - L. There are a lot of extraneous computers in this list I don't need to work on, so I wrote a little Python script to pull out the bad values from the computer list (what was in column A). I then inserted a column to the left of column A (so what was in A is now in B and the good values are in A). I basically need to keep column A as it is, make column B match it and also remove the corresponding specs of the computers I don't need to worry about, but keep everything sorted so I know what specs go with what computer I need to work. Is there any way to do this in Excel?

thanks

Comment: can you share some table,column,row, some visual things?

Comment: When I go to paste it the formatting is lost ... I can't show the real data because it is company info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlookup should do the trick

Assuming the current source data looks like this:

```
    A   A   1   2   3   5   6
    D   B   7   8   9   10  11
    F   C   12  13  14  15  16
        D   17  18  19  20  21
        E   22  23  24  25  26
        F   27  28  29  30  31
        G   32  33  34  35  36
```

and desired output is this

```
    A   1   2   3   5   6
    D   17  18  19  20  21
    F   27  28  29  30  31
```

On a new sheet to keep it clean

Assuming SHeet1 has your current data
in Sheet2 column a  Sheet4!A1
in Sheet2 column B  VLOOKUP(Sheet4!B1,Sheet4!$B$1:$G$7,2,0)
VLOOKUP(Sheet4!B1,Sheet4!$B$1:$G$7,3,0) for column C and etc

dirty and tedious, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try adding data into columnA (new) based on whether the (new) columnB values feature in the good list (elsewhere), say with [MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx). If they do not `#N/A` should be returned and that might be used to filter on and delete what is visible.

If your 'good' list is in Sheet2 column C you might try:

```
=MATCH(B1,Sheet2!C:C,0)
```

copied down to suit.